# MPMediaPickerController error?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

Hello when I am trying to use `MPMediaPickerController` for selecting the music I am getting this error:

```
<MPRemoteMediaPickerController: 0x17d6c390> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MusicUIService
```

I am using this code:

```
_mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
_mediaPicker.delegate = self;
_mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
_mediaPicker.showsCloudItems = NO;
[_mediaPicker loadView];
```

Could any please guide why is this error occurring. After doing the research I came to know that its occurred due to the custom font. But even after removing the same from the `UIViewController` its giving the same error.